# WPF control SetValue difference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

What is the difference between those 2 lines?

The first one does what I expect it to do. It changes the width.
When using the second one, nothing happens. Why?

1)

```
columnSplitter.Width = new GridLength(myWidth);
```

2)

```
columnSplitter.SetValue(GridSplitter.WidthProperty, myWidth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
columnSplitter.Width = new GridLength(myWidth);
```

indicates that `columnSplitter` is a `ColumnDefinition` (which has a `Width` property of type `GridLength`), not a `GridSplitter` (which has a `Width` property of type `double`).

Obviously, you can't set `GridSplitter.WidthProperty` on a `ColumnDefinition`, and the equivalent value assignment would be

```
columnSplitter.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(myWidth));
```